# Attach jQuery plugins to RequireJS loaded jQuery on a page with multiple versions of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, requirejs

*Good morrow!*

I've spent many days searching for a similar question and answer, but can't find (or maybe understand) any similar ones.

***The Summary***

I am adding onto a series of pages for a client that currently use `jQuery 1.4.2`. I am limited in that existing code must stay as is, and cannot be leveraged that much.

Yadda, yadda, yadda. All I've built thus far uses `RequireJS 2.1.9`, `jQuery 1.10.2`, and my own modules. I've made a jQuery loader module that calls `$.noConflict(true)` and all that good stuff to ensure my modules get `1.10.2` and I don't intrude on the globally necessary `1.4.2`.

Below is an similar example of my current RequireJS configuration:

```
{
    baseUrl: '/some/path',
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'lib/path/jquery',
        'jquery-loader': 'lib/path/jquery-loader',
        'jquery-validator': 'lib/path/jquery-validator'
    },
    map: {
        '*': {
            'jquery': 'jquery-loader'
        },
        'jquery-loader': {
            'jquery': 'jquery'
        }
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery-validator': ['jquery']
    }
}
```

***The Problem***

Some coworkers need to use some plugins inside my new code, namely `jquery-validator`.

My problem is that with the current configuration above, `jquery-validator`, which is a non-AMD plugin gets set to the globally available jQuery (1.4.2) instead of my jQuery (1.10.2) despite the entire setup.

I'd rather all the new code not have to use the globally available jQuery just to get to the validator plugin.

***The Question***

I'm not sure how I can get this to go as I want it, but my question is: is there actually *any* way to get this to work without me having to go into `jquery-validator` and wrap it in a define call?

Comment: It really depends on the code in `jquery-validator`.  If it accesses the global variable `jQuery` or `$` then you have to modify the file itself, or do something ugly like temporarily overwrite the global variables with your local version while it's loading.